# Which one is more efficient? select 1 row totalsize 10mb or select 10k row totalsize 10mb?

Tags: sql

Which one is more efficient? select 1 row totalsize 10mb or select 10k row totalsize 10mb?

understand the efficiency of query

Comment: If you have one row there's not a lot of point in using SQL. You might as well keep it in a text file. With 10k rows you can select, manipulate and format your query to give the information needed. We often run queries which run results less than 1% the size of the tables used.

Comment: If you want to know what's the more efficient of two options, here's a general tip. Always works. Implement the two options, measure the timings. And if you did that, and you have two use cases, and the code, and the measurements, and can't figure out why one is faster than the other, *then* you can come here, present your cases, and ask if someone can explain the difference. Without any of that, this question is unlikely to be helpful to anybody (including yourself).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation of a particular SQL (or NoSQL) server. Usually, it is not a good idea to store big records in the DB, though. The smaller- the better. At the very least, it's easier to query data from 100 columns than from 10Mb of raw data in 1 column.